# Sidebar sorting issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I take 3 posts on to the main home page to display them and i know some of them have weird dates going back to 1987, the idea is to get the latest 4 posts into the home page but on the sidebar im not seeing the truth.

This is the code along with the latestPost variable which takes care of showing a post in the center of the page, what im talking about is mainly the posts on the sidebar.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $latestPost = Post::latest()->first();

        $posts = Post::query()
            ->where('active', '=', 1)
            ->whereDate('published_at', '<', Carbon::now())
            ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
            ->take(3)->get();
        return view('home', compact('posts', 'latestPost'));
    }
```

Im not seeing any errors but im wondering why for example "doom 3" is not presented there since that post is more recent than "doom 2", see here for the list of dates: https://imgur.com/a/uf9ugGN, and here's a pic of where things are on the main page: https://imgur.com/JaTwL9V, so like i said previously, "doom 3" should be the post on top, right?

how im iterating the posts on the sidebar and the center of the main page, first it checks for the $latestPost and then at the bottom is for the iteration of the latest 3 posts, but excluding the "main last post"

```
<x-app-layout meta-description="Sick Of Metal blog for the metalhead with rock and heavy metal news and much more">
    <div class="md:col-start-2 md:col-end-6 lg:col-start-2 lg:col-end-4 md:mx-auto">
        <article class="relative">
            <a href="{{ route('view', $latestPost) }}">
                <img src="{{ $latestPost->getThumbnail() }}" alt="">
                <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 px-4 py-2 bg-gradient-to-t from-black">
                    <h1 class="font-bold">LATEST NEWS</h1>    
                    <h3 class="text-xl text-white font-bold">
                        {{ $latestPost->title }}
                    </h3>
                    <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-300">
                        {{ $latestPost->shortBody() }}
                    </p>
                </div> <!-- latest news end -->
            </a>
        </article>  
    </div> <!-- latest articles end -->
    
    <div class="md:col-start-1 md:row-start-1 md:mx-auto lg:w-2/3">
        <h1 class="font-bold px-4">LATEST NEWS</h1>
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <x-post-item :post="$post"></x-post-item>
        @endforeach
    </div> <!-- latest news list end -->

    <x-sidebar/>
</x-app-layout>
```

post-item.blade.php

```
<article class="shadow my-4 px-4 py-3 flex-col">
    <a href="{{ route('view', $post) }}">
        <img class="pr-2" src="{{ $post->getThumbnail() }}">
    </a>
    <div>
        @foreach($post->categories as $category)
            <a href="#" class="text-blue-700 text-sm font-bold uppercase pb-4">
                {{ $category->title }}
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <a href="{{ route('view', $post) }}">
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold">
            {{$post->title}}
        </h3>
    </a>
</article>
```

As for the screenshot ( https://imgur.com/a/uf9ugGN ), its showing these values:

published at: "june 4 2023" | user: "guarpig" | updated at: "jun 5 2023"

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 2048);
            $table->string('slug', 2048);
            $table->string('thumbnail', 2048)->nullable();
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->datetime('published_at')->nullable();
            $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\User::class, 'user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have tried using the "created_at" field instead of "published_at" on the `index()` function. I need to ensure that the published_at dates of the posts are accurate on the sidebar. My goal is to show 4 posts, for now at least, on the main homepage. Have the latest the just published post at the center, and the following posts previous to the latest on the side.

After removing get and take from the function I took the query from the `index()` and ran it on MySQL:

```
"select * from `posts` where `active` = ? and date(`published_at`) < ? order by `published_at` desc"
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM  `posts` where  `active` = 1  and date(`published_at`) <= '2023-06-05 15:00:00' order by  `published_at` desc;
+----+
| id | title                                                  | slug                                              | thumbnail                                                                                    | body                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | active | published_at        | user_id | created_at          | updated_at          | meta_title | meta_description    |
+----+
| 17 | doom 3                                                 | doom-3                                            | 1b8whd1HfrFbLA3sFne8EQK51kdycw-metaZHVjdGFwZS0wMi5wbmc=-.png                                 | <p>yea</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |      1 | 2023-06-05 08:00:00 |       1 | 2023-06-05 16:13:55 | 2023-06-05 16:54:39 | NULL       | NULL                |
| 18 | doom 6                                                 | doom-6                                            | SYrdpa1ZcI0scVaIkHViqq6z4Tn1BI-metaY3JhY2tlZF9wYXR0ZXJuX3RleHR1cmVfYmFja2dyb3VuZC5qcGc=-.jpg | <p>donde aparece este post? y como se ve</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |      1 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 |       1 | 2023-06-05 16:14:40 | 2023-06-05 17:43:08 | NULL       | my meta description |
| 16 | doom metal 2                                           | doom-metal-2                                      | GPkO6NnUkJeSvo5lFKFG29WJd5AKWb-metad2ViLmpwZw==-.jpg                                         | <p>doom metal active</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |      1 | 2023-06-04 00:00:00 |       1 | 2023-06-05 01:09:02 | 2023-06-05 01:09:02 | NULL       | NULL                |
| 14 | Alice! when she first saw the Mock Turtle: 'crumbs.    | alice-when-she-first-saw-the-mock-turtle-crumbs   | ECEvIh07WrKg4FzGwQA4ztxKXOzUbb-metaY3JhY2tlZF9wYXR0ZXJuX3RleHR1cmVfYmFja2dyb3VuZC5qcGc=-.jpg | How queer everything is queer to-day.' |      1 | 2022-06-05 11:47:38 |       1 | 2023-06-02 04:42:47 | 2023-06-05 02:18:32 | NULL       | NULL                |
| 13 | Cat in a melancholy tone. 'Nobody seems to like her.   | cat-in-a-melancholy-tone-nobody-seems-to-like-her | v98NtC5ESyuHZLhfkNReFwLawtVHtC-metaZHVjdGFwZS0wMi5wbmc=-.png                                 | Seven looked up eagerly, half hoping she might as well she might, what a long way. |      1 | 2014-08-21 11:17:02 |       1 | 2023-06-02 04:42:47 | 2023-06-05 15:58:25 | NULL       | NULL                |
| 12 | Why, I do wonder what Latitude or Longitude either.    | why-i-do-wonder-what-latitude-or-longitude-either | jZBxIwXcS0jeyzg11fnIcNS95ARbgN-metaZ3JpZC1jb2xzLTIuanBn-.jpg                                 | Alice as she could do to hold it.  |      1 | 2012-09-01 00:47:05 |       1 | 2023-06-02 04:42:47 | 2023-06-05 00:17:14 | NULL       | NULL                |
| 15 | Five! Don't go splashing paint over me like that!' By. | five-dont-go-splashing-paint-over-me-like-that-by | KX9o6eLkS4HmuyeCnwDgJpnkHvtwap-metaZ3JpZC5qcGc=-.jpg                                         | Hatter: 'let's all move one place on.' He moved on as he shook both his shoes on. 'I'm on the breeze that followed them, the melancholy words:-- 'Soo--oop of the. |      1 | 1987-01-24 22:40:46 |       1 | 2023-06-02 04:42:47 | 2023-06-05 00:16:12 | NULL       | NULL                |
+----+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: `Carbon::now()` includes the current time (`2023-06-05 17:23:54`), and you're using that to filter `published_at`; `doom 3` has a `published_at` timestamp that includes the time; maybe it's getting filtered out by that clause (hard to say with timezones and whatnot).

Comment: So i guess it just "works" now? I've edited the question with an SQL query that I ran, after doing this i started seeing other posts that it wasn't showing. I edited the names and dates of the posts to see if the "main" post would not appear on the sidebar and it turned out okay... not sure what this means..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing `where` instead of `whereDate` solved the issue of not being able to see my posts on the sidebar.

Using `->whereDate('published_at', '<', now())` means:

1. Look at the published_at column, but ignore the timestamp – only look at the date (that’s Date A)
2. Compare that date to today’s date, again ignoring the timestamp (that’s Date B)
3. Only fetch rows where Date A is less than Date B

Example: If i created 2 posts today, neither one of those two posts would show up today until a day had gone by. That is why I wasn't able to see "doom 3" in the sidebar.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::query()
        ->where('active', '=', 1)
        ->where('published_at', '<', Carbon::now())
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->take(4)
        ->get()
    ;

    $latestPost = $posts->shift();

    return view('home', compact('posts', 'latestPost'));
}
```

Another change, the use of `$posts->shift();` exclusively selects the latest resource created, which is what i got there to get the latest post.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-shift